# Editing a specific line of a large file

Tags: python, file, rubiks-cube

I am creating the pruning tables for a Rubik's Cube solver, and this means I need to create a file mapping a unique identifier for any cube to a number in the range 0 to 25 which represents the distance the cube is from the solved state (25 is the maximum depth I am using).  However, the identifiers can go from 0 to about 4.7 * 10^21, or about 2^72, so they cannot be used as indexes in a conventional data structure because they are well outside the bounds of an integer.  Also, the pruning table will need to be checked millions of times, so I need lookups to be quick.

So, my idea was to create a file where the id of a cube was used as the line number and the depth was stored there.  I would convert the depth to base 26 so each line of the file would hold exactly one character from a to z.  But, I need to write a character to a specific line of the file and I'd prefer not t read the thousands of lines before it.  So, I was wondering if there is a way to edit a specific line of a file if I know that every line contains exactly one character.

For example, the id of the solved cube is 591305913000000, so the 591305913000000th line with store a 0, because it is 0 moves from the solved cube.  The id of a cube with the move `R` performed on it has an id 5889210210000498 and a 1 will be stored at the 5889210210000498th line.

I am also open to suggestions on a better way to store all of this data in a way that can quickly be read.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are the identifiers a deterministic function of the cube state? That is, if I have two cubes and they are in the same state, will they get the same id?

Comment: Realize, even if you only use one byte per line, you're looking at having 4.7*10^21 bytes of data.  Just to review: gigabyte is 10^9, terrabyte is 10^12, petabyte is 10^15.  Where will you store this file?

Comment: You could use [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to get to a file location, and as you're planning it now, you know that each line is 2 bytes long, so just seek to `id*2`.  You can even get rid of the linefeeds, and half your file size (just seek to id and read one byte).  But you're talking a huge file, that can't exist on any system I'm aware of.

Comment: How many millions of terabyte drives do you have access to?

Comment: @PM2Ring I can do the math!  acn3 would only need 4700 million terrabyte drives.  :-D

Comment: To do this stuff you _really_ need to take advantage of symmetry, like [Tom Rokicki and friends did](http://www.cube20.org). And even then they had a _lot_ of distributed computing power & storage at their disposal.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube#Mathematics the total number of permutations a cube can have is under 4.4 X 10^19. That's still too many to store all of them, but where are you getting the extra 100 fold permutations from?

Comment: Assuming you _do_ figure out some clever symmetry tricks, you don't need to consume 2 bytes for each state. You only need 5 bits to hold a number in range(26), so that can be stored in a single byte. Or if you do bit packing, you can store the depth info for 8 cube states in 5 bytes, but of course all that bit packing & unpacking will slow down the access speed somewhat. Also, this is going to take a very long time, so you probably should be doing it in a compiled language, rather than Python.

Comment: @DavyKavanagh Not every number in the id range is mapped to a cube.  It sounds like I need a new system of identification that uses symmetry.